# How to check if 'next' field in loop is the same?

Tags: python

I am paginating through an API, which uses two different methods - next token & next timestamp.

For unknown to me reasons, sometimes at the end of a call the next token will be the same, which leaves me stuck in an endless loop. The same happens if I use the next timestamp.

However, I have noticed that this could be avoided if I use a combination of the two.

This is the loop I am currently running:

```
while int(JSONContent['next'][0:10])>unixtime_yesterday:
    try:
        url='www.website.com?next'+JSONContent['next'][0:10]+'api_key'
        JSONContent = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers).json()
        temp_df=json_normalize(JSONContent['data'])
        df=df.append(temp_df,ignore_index=True,sort=False)
    except ValueError: 
        print('There was a JSONDecodeError')
```

This is a normal result of the JSONContent['next'] field. The first 10 characters are the timestamp and the last 10 are the other token:
`'1650377727-3feWs8592va'`

How can I check if the next timestamp is the same as the current one, so that I can then use the token instead of the timestamp?

In layman terms I want to do the following:

```
if JSONContent['next'][0:10][current_cycle]=JSONContent['next'][0:10][next_cycle]:
   token=JSONContent['next'][11:22][next_cycle]
else:
   token=JSONContent['next'][0:10][next_cycle]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just the "next next" before you're passing on to the next iteration, send another request and check for equality between the next and the next next.

```py
import time

time_stamp= time.time()

using_token = False

while using_token or int(time_stamp) > unixtime_yesterday:
    try:
        url = 'www.website.com?next'+JSONContent['next'][0:10]+'api_key'
        JSONContent = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers).json()

        next_url = 'www.website.com?next'+JSONContent['next'][0:10]+'api_key'
        next_JSONContent = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers).json()

        if JSONContent['next'][0:10] == next_JSONContent['next'][0:10]:
            using_token = True
        else:
            time_stamp = JSONContent['next'][0:10]
            using_token = False

        temp_df = json_normalize(JSONContent['data'])
        df = df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
    except ValueError:
        print('There was a JSONDecodeError')
```

You can also initialize the using_token to true, but it's break clean code rule of naming.